# How to log messages to collection with fixed size and rotately

Tags: mongodb

I converted the `error_logs` collection with fixed size,

But when the size is reach max, it won't insert any new log.

I want to remove the oldest log automatically. how could I do that.

```
db.runCommand( { convertToCapped: 'error_logs', size: 10000 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the "size" argument with the "max" argument, as they are two different things. The "max" is the number of records and "size" is the total size in bytes that the collection can grow to:

From [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#create-a-capped-collection):

> Additionally, you may also specify a maximum number of documents for the collection using the max field as in the following document:

```js
    db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 } )
```

So you are **required** to set the "size", but the real governor here is "max" for the number of documents to be there.

Work out the "size" of your documents multiplied by the number of entries to be just a bit larger that what you would expect for 10,000 documents at set that value along with "max" as 10,000.

Note that "size" is always respected regarless. So if that "size" is met before the "max" documents, then oldest data will be removed from the collection in order to stay under the "size" limit. So make it bigger than what you expect, if you want the document "max" limit to always apply.

i.e.:

```js
db.collection.stats().avgObjSize * 11000
```

Then the oldest document will automatically be removed as a new one is added at 10,000 documents "max" limit.

Example:

```js
db.createCollection( "log", { "capped": true, "size": 3894000, "max": 1000 })

var bulk = db.log.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

for ( var i = 1; i <=10000; i++ ) {
  bulk.insert({ "_id": i });

  if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.log.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }
}

db.log.count();
db.log.find().limit(1);
db.log.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1);
```

Produces this output:

```js
> db.log.count();
1000
> db.log.find().limit(1);
{ "_id" : 9001 }
> db.log.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1);
{ "_id" : 10000 }
```

So there are clearly only 1000 entries and the older documents are removed with only the last 1000 remaining.